# Isoprenoid Diphosphate Concentration in Yeast saccharomyces cerevisiae

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, bioinformatics, metabolism, yeast

Isoprenoid  Diphosphate(IPP) is an important metabolites which is precursor in lot of secondary metabolites like Dolichol diphosphate, ubiquinone, prenylated proteins and carotenoid (not synthesized in s cerevisiae).

What is the average concentration of IPP present in yeast per gm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this information doesn't provide a direct answer to your question, I hope that it sets the scene for what is achievable in metabolic engineering from IPP. It should also provide a jumping off point for further literature research.

This is a fairly recent review of metabolic engineering of relevant pathways in various microbial systems, including *Saccaharmoyes*:

> Ajikumar  PK *et al*. (2008)  Terpenoids: Opportunities for Biosynthesis of Natural Product Drugs Using Engineered Microorganisms. Molecular Pharmaceutics 5:167–190

The review refers to:

> Ro, D. *et al.* (2006) Production of the antimalarial drug precursor artemisinic acid in engineered yeast. Nature 440, 940–943.

In this work, the introduction of a pathway-specific gene led to the production of 4.4 mg L<sup>-1</sup> of product. This was increased to 153 mg L<sup>-1</sup> by several manipulations including:

Increasing flux through the pathway by expressing a modified HMG CoA reductase

Decreasing flux into sterol synthesis by downregulation of the *ERG9* gene combined with expression of a dominant negative allele of the transcription factor Upc2.

**UPDATE**

After posting my answer I found this paper:

> Huang, B. *et al*. (2011) Metabolite target analysis of isoprenoid pathway in Saccharomyces cerevisiae in response to genetic modification by GC-SIM-MS coupled with chemometrics. Metabolomics 7:134–146

The paper includes a detailed discussion of methodologies, which I won't go into here.

Although there are no measurements of IPP, in Table 7 they present this result: geranyl pyrophosphate 32 ng ml<sup>-1</sup> in a 48 h culture, A<sub>600</sub> ~ 2.3. *ERG9* disruption increased this to 56 ng ml<sup>-1</sup>

As far as I can tell these values are presented as ng ml<sup>-1</sup> original culture. Using 1 U of OD600 corresponds to 0.41 g of dry cells liter−1 taken from [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC404389/) I calculate a value for GPP of 34 µg g<sup>-1</sup> dry weight in the wild-type strain.